# For an old girl, she moves fast

Tags: phrases

What does the following phrase generally mean?

> For an old girl, she moves fast. For a saber, you are pretty soft.
>   For a guy I barely know, you are really starting to annoy me.

Does the structure [For X, Y] mean Y is typically unusual for X?
For example, old girls are not fast, but for her, it's exception to her.

Comment: ***For***:  1) *despite; notwithstanding*: she's a good wife, for all her nagging;. 2) *Considering the nature or usual character of*: was spry for his advanced age.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for

Comment: We'all are presupposing that the OP knows the idiom with "considering". He might not, so let's answer his question strictly in his own terms: Santanu, your last sentence, yes you got it. This one moves much faster than you would expect from an old girl. The sabre is softer than you would normally expect.

Comment: what is this question about?

Comment: Try the excellent ELL site, Santanu.

Answer (score 8):

The function word "for" has a lot of different meanings and the "for" in your example means, considering the fact that she is old she moves very fast.

As most function words have several meanings the normal way to study those words is consulting a grammar where the main uses of such function words are explained and then studying them in a dictionary, in book form or online.

***[OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/for_1)*** has an entry for "for" as preposition and one for "for" as conjunction. "For" as used in your example is covered under preposition, meaning number 12.

Comment: Thanks to Josh61 for editing the link and to Little Eva  for the compliment.

Comment: Typo: FUNCTION and if you place an asterisk * on either side of a word, the word is italicized, e.g.  The function word *for* has a lot of different meanings ... two asterisks either side (no space) will place the word in bold e.g. **for**. Three asterisks will produce this effect e.g. ***for***.

Comment: Likewise. I have searched in vain to find this on meta. I learned _part of it_, only by **editing other posts**.  I still don't know if there is a way to underline.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Underlines are usually a bad idea because they can be easily mistaken for links.

Comment: But nobody has used links for what 30 years??  (i mean "always underlined!" links.)  underlining is cool.

Answer (score 1):

We use the phrase ***For an X ...*** like this to mean *compared to other Xes*. It isn't always the case that the quality described is unusual. Here are a couple of examples:

- For a professor, she's quite inexperienced.
- For students her age this is quite normal.

You can see that in the second example, the speaker is saying that the situation is quite normal and not unusual at all.